# add role by clicking on a link discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm currently developing a discord bot that grabs the user IP, with their permission.
For that I would like that once they clicked on the link I'd display on the embed that the bot has given them the verified role.
I'm facing some issues with this.

My code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import requests
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import socket
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!", case_insensitive = True)
BOT_TOKEN = "my_token"

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Connected to bot: {}'.format(bot.user.name))
    print('Bot ID: {}'.format(bot.user.id))
    print(''' 
 
    ██████╗░░░█████╗░████████╗███████╗░
    ██╔══██╗░██╔══██╗╚══██╔══╝██╔════╝░ 
    ██████╦╝░██║░░██║░░░██║░░░█████╗░░░ 
    ██╔══██╗░██║░░██║░░░██║░░░██╔══╝░░░
    ██████╦╝░╚█████╔╝░░░██║░░░███████╗░
    ╚═════╝░░░╚════╝░░░░╚═╝░░░╚══════╝░
    ''')
    print('\nConnected to bot: {}'.format(bot.user.name))
    print('Bot ID: {}'.format(bot.user.id))
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="Grabbing your stuff"))

@bot.command()
async def verify(ctx):  
    nome=ctx.author.name
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=nome,
        description = ':flag_pt:Clica [aqui]("site") para te verificares\n :flag_us:Click [here]("site") to verify',
        colour = discord.Colour.green()
    )

    botmsg = await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    await botmsg.add_reaction("✅")


bot.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

Comment: What is the error you face?

Comment: You can't really do that with the bot, discord doesn't tell you when a user clicks on a link. Why not do it on the server side? You could have a function that simply gives the role when someone visits it. Another a bit more difficult approach (but more robust) would be the use of websockets. When the user visits the site, it will send some data, then add the role with the bot.

Comment: like i have this php file that will return the information to discord throw an webhook, but i dont know how to implment the file in my website :/